# How do I disable the intercept of PrtScrn in WPF apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, screenshot

Possibly this is better asked on a different StackExchange site, or just reported as a bug to Microsoft, although I'm approaching this as an app developer.

I have my Win10 box configured so that pressing PrtScrn runs the Snip & Sketch overlay (the screen fades and controls appear at the top of the screen, allowing selection of a rectangular or other area to specifically snip, rather than capturing the whole display).  This normally works fine.

However, I have noticed that whenever I have a WPF app focused, pressing PrtScrn is apparently intercepted and silently copies the whole screen to the clipboard instead of displaying the Snip & Sketch overlay, as in previous versions of Windows or with Snip & Sketch disabled.  Presumably somewhere in the framework WPF is intercepting this key and doing its own thing, or otherwise interfering with Snip & Sketch's hotkey.

I can work around this by focusing a different app while keeping the WPF app visible and then pressing the key, which allows capturing the WPF app.  But this is inconvenient and silly.

As an app developer, is there some way to disable this interception so that (at least for my apps) PrtScrn works as intended?

Comment: Use Window Key hook event and capture PrintSCreenKey. override any clipboard data after that.

Comment: That's the answer to a different question.  Snip & Sketch is presumably already doing this -- it just doesn't work when a WPF app has keyboard focus.

Comment: I mean Windows API. it hooks all keyboard inputs even your app doesn't have any focus.

Comment: Again, I think you are misunderstanding the question.

Comment: You may want to subscribe to `KeyDown` event and set `e.Handled = true;` in your WPF app.